# How can the button show the permission on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want, when the website notification is granted we see green button, when it is denied see the red button. Button is have a CSS style and checkbox. By the way, this button will not have any permission to grant or allow any permission on the page. Just the button will show the previous permission.

**button html**

```
<label for="button">
    <input type="checkbox" id="button" />
    <span class="arka"></span
</label>
```

**sample javascript code**

```
function bildirim () {
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    } 
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    }
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I dont know where you want to call the function, nor what notification is I'll just post how to add a css-class to something.

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.setAttribute('class', grantedClass);
```